# C++: Why does my function return a reference address different from the dereferenced pointer's address?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I was under the impression that addresses of references to a dereferenced pointer were the same as the address of the pointer ([so question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060392/is-the-address-of-a-reference-to-a-dereferenced-pointer-the-same-as-the-address)).

But when I write a function that returns a reference of a dereferenced pointer, I'm getting a different address from the original:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int buff[10] = {0};
int& getSecond();

int main(){
    buff[0] = 5;
    buff[1] = 10;
    buff[2] = 15;

    int second = getSecond();
    int* sp = (int*)&second;

    cout << "second:" << *sp << " third?" << *(sp+1) << endl;
    cout << "second:" << *(buff + 1) << " third: " << *(buff + 2) << endl;
    cout << "Buff " << *buff << " addr:" << &(*buff) << " reffy: " << &second << endl;
}

int& getSecond(){
    return *(buff + 1);
}
```

The output I'm getting from that is:

```
second:10 third?-16121856
second:10 third: 15
Buff 5 addr:0x8050b80 reffy: 0xbf7089b0
```

Is the function creating a temporary variable and returning its address or something?  I can't quite figure out why it would be doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a variable called `second`, which gets assigned the value returned by `getSecond()`. If I understand your question correctly, you perhaps meant to write:

```
int& second = getSecond();
// ^
// Mind the reference symbol
```

This way, `second` would actually be a reference to the second element of `buff`, rather than a separate variable with its own address, and the initialization:

```
int* sp = (int*)&second;
//        ^^^^^^
//        By the way, this is not necessary!
```

Would make `sp` point to the second element of `buff` (which seems to be what you expect) rather than to a separate variable called `second`. As mentioned in the comments (thanks to DyP for noticing), the cast is superfluous (and you should not use C-style casts), so you should rewrite it just as:

```
int* sp = &second;
```

Comment: What's the conversion for?

Comment: @DyP: In fact, it's not needed. I just copy-pasted the OP's code. Will mention that, thank you

Answer (score 2):

`getSecond` may return a reference to the second element of `buff`, but you then copy it into the variable `second`:

```
int second = getSecond();
```

So when you do `&second`, you get the address of `second`, not of the `buff` element.

You'll need to make `second` a reference too, to get the output you expect:

```
int& second = getSecond();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is the function creating a temporary variable

No, **you** are creating one:

```
int second = getSecond();
```

should be

```
int &second = getSecond();
```

Comment: Yep, it use the copy constructor instead of copying the reference.