# Address of reference to this not the same as this

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have the following snippet of code:

```
class Base {
//...
};

class Subclass : public Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        Base& ref = (*this);
    }
//...
};
```

Where I pass this reference to the constructor of some other objects for later use.  According to the following article (and what I know about references), if I get the address of *ref*, it should be the same as *this*.

[Is the address of a reference to a dereferenced pointer the same as the address of the pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060392/is-the-address-of-a-reference-to-a-dereferenced-pointer-the-same-as-the-address)

However, this is what I am seeing when I run the code:

```
this    0x20002288 
&ref    0x20003314
```

The addresses are NOT the same.  Does anyone know why this would be?

Thanks!

Comment: Reference are _sometimes_ just different names for the same object, and _sometimes_ they are an actual object that passes through all usages to the referred object. :(

Comment: The way you set this up in the question makes me think that there's more to it. Please make a [mre]. You can build on [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5an799) if you'd like.

Comment: @MooingDuck Could you elaborate on this a bit more? If my reference is not just a different name for 'this', then what is it referring to exactly?  The subclass itself?

Comment: I mean, you're bringing inheritance into the mix, maybe vtables. You don't show enough code. Like how you're even getting your output.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Just by you saying that, I wonder if my problem is due to the fact that the real class I am testing with is using multiple inheritance...

Comment: Minimal example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rTznTv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the source of the problem, and it has to do with multiple inheritance. Here is a simplified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base1 {
private:
    int _a;
    int _b;
};

class Base2 {
public:
    ~Base2() {
        
    }
    
    virtual void* foo() = 0;
    
private:
    int _x;
};

class Child : public Base1, public Base2 {
public:
    void* foo() override {
        Base1& baseRef = (*this);
        return static_cast<void*>(&baseRef);
    }

private:
    int _c;
};

int main() {
    Child c;

    printf("&c=%p\r\n",&c);
    printf("c.foo()=%p\r\n",c.foo());
    
    Base2* c2 = new Child;
    
    printf("c2=%p\r\n",c2);
    printf("c2->foo()=%p\r\n",c2->foo());

    return 0;
}
```

Where the output is:

```
&c=000000000061FDF0
c.foo()=000000000061FDFC
c2=00000000007034A0
c2->foo()=00000000007034AC
```